# 月日を表す引数の型は何が適切なのでしょうか

Tags: python, プログラミング言語

Pythonに限った話ではありませんが、
月日を引数に取りたい場合、どのように指定にするのが適切でしょうか？
dateやdatetimeオブジェクトだとyearは不要で利用する側がyearを指定しないといけないので違うかなと思っています。
月と日を分けると配列でまとめて受け取れませんし文字列だと複数のフォーマットが存在してしまいます。

Comment: 「月日を引数に取りたい場合」とは自作関数の引数の話でしょうか？

Comment: はい。自作関数の引数です。

Comment: 「月日を引数に取りたい」ことと「月と日を配列でまとめて受け取りたい」ことは一応は独立した条件では？ 常に両方を必須にするのか、配列は不要な場合があるのか、それぞれの時はどんな形式が良いのか、そして何故 年の情報が不要(あるいはかえって邪魔)なのか？といった、希望する内容・適用条件・場合分け等をもう少し詳細に記述したほうが良いでしょう。広い範囲に応用できる知識を得ようとしてかえって問題が曖昧になっている感じです。現在困っている問題・課題を具体的に書いた方が的確な助言・回答を得やすいと思われます。

Comment: 「年」は不要なのであれば、`from datetime import date`, `date(year=1, month=6, day=12)` などとしてもよいのではないでしょうか。もしくは `dataclass` で `month`, `day` のみの attribute を持った型を作成してもよいかもしれません。

Comment: 仕様を定義する際「〜 だとyearを指定しないといけないので違うかな」と思えるなら, その説明を質問に加え 現状を伝えるのがよいでしょう。例えば指定月日から月末までの日数を返す関数を想定すると, 年は指定があればそれ無ければ今年 みたいな引数にすると思うので

Answer (score 3):

コンテナとして利用可能な型(`list`, `tuple`, `dict`, `dataclass`, etc.)であれば何でもよいかと思いますが、一例として `dataclass` を使う場合を挙げておきます。(`dataclass` は Python 3.7 以降で使用可能)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MonthDay:
    month: int
    day: int

def myfunction(md: MonthDay) -> None:
    print(md.month)
    print(md.day)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myfunction(MonthDay(month=6, day=12))
```